cURL to Openshift console to get access token (using OpenID Connect)
I am trying to get a username or access token of the user currently logged into OpenShift (here is a similar question) from the pod Terminal. I need to log all the commands that are executed in the terminal and I need to include also the username who execute those commands. The problem is that OpenShift uses OpenID for authentication , which means it doesn't use a classic user/password, it accepts a token from the authentication server, this is the reason I cannot use the curl -ks -u user:pass https://xxx....
I bound the cluster admin role to the service account just for testing to avoid the permissions issue and tried oc whoami -t in the pod terminal, but it shows the token of the service account the pod is running on. I also tried oc  get useroauthaccesstoken , no result because it checks the service account. There is no problem with permissions as oc get oauthaccesstoken will return a list of all users including tokens.
Does anyone have an idea if it's possible to use cURL or another solution to get the username/token into the pod?

Not sure for what you are looking for exactly, but the information related to the service account should be mounted in your pod under/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccountincluding the token
Also the linux userid running the process can be retrieved with theidcommand...:
id
uid=1000720000(1000720000) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1000720000

